# Python don't leak package in namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.10

I have a package layout like this:

```
\package
\package\__init__.py
\package\process
\package\process\__init__.py
\package\utils
\package\utils\__init__.py
```

Inside `\package\process\__init__.py` I need to import stuff from the `utils` subpackage, but i do not want to leak `utils` into the `process` subpackage namespace. That is, if i simply do `from .. import utils` in the `process` subpackage, then users can access `utils` through `package.process.utils`, i don't want that. So i tried:

```py
from .. import utils
def function1(arg: utils.DeviceType):
    return utils.helper(arg)
del utils
```

but when i then later call `function1`, this crashes because `name 'utils' is not defined`. I guess that is due to the `del` statement. One way to prevent this leak would be to do the import only in the function body, but i need it in the main namespace as above because of the type annotation for the function argument. I now solved it like this:

```py
from .. import utils
def function1(arg: utils.DeviceType):
    from .. import utils    # need to import again, previous top-level one was just for the type annotation, and needed to be deleted to not befoul this package's namespace
    return utils.helper(arg)
del utils
```

These seems ugly and not optimal, doing the import twice. Am i missing something? Is there another way to solve this? I could `from .. import utils as _utils` so its at least not at an obvious name and flagged as internal to the user, but wouldn't that still leak out?

Comment: Define`__all__` in your `__init__.py`

Comment: Why do you care if users can use `package.process.utils` instead of `package.utils` directly?

Comment: You can use `from .. import utils as _utils` instead. This will at least prevent `_utils` from being exposed via `from package.process import *`, but users can still access it directly if they know it exists.

Comment: @chepner: I want users to use `package.utils`, and not `package.process.utils`. Good to know that underscored names won't get exported unless directly referenced. Thats the solution then.

Comment: It's not something I would worry about. The same people who will jump through hoops to write `import package.process.utils` can still write `import package.proces._utils`. The best you can do is not import the name `util` at all, and so something like `from ..utils import foo, bar, baz`. (And people will *still* be able to access `package.process.foo` et al. if they really want to.)

Comment: Documentation is your friend here: if you don't document it that `package.process` uses `utils`, users can't complain later if it stops working. (Even better, you can document that `utils` is an implementation detail and should *not* be relied on.)